# Change shape of UICollectionViewCell gesture hitbox

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a bunch of `UICollectionViewCells` which look circular (imagine a circular background image). I want to detect when I tap on one of them, but currently the gesture hitbox of the cells are square-shaped corresponding to the cell height and width. As a result, tapping on the corner of the square shape, which is a bit outside of the circular look, still registers as a gesture:

[image: circle in square]

I'm thinking of a way to do this while still being able to use the `indexPathForItemAtPoint(point:)` method i.e. I don't want to write a manual check, such as a `for` loop running `cell.frame.containsPoint(point:)`.

I tried to change the `borderRadius` of the cell's layer, but I think the relevant field used to detect the tap is the `frame`, which is a `CGRect`...so is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying to do, or must I write the cell detection code myself? (something like, get all cells and calculate the distance to the center, and then see if the distance is within the radius)

The main problem is that my layout causes cell frames to overlap, so `indexPathForItemAtPoint(point:)` currently causes some cells to be favored over others when their frames overlap (most likely based on iteration order through `visibleCells`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UIBezierPath and check if the tap is within that. For example in your action for a UITapGestureRecognizer you can say something like

```
let location = sender.location
let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(location)
let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
let newLocation = cell?.convertPoint(location, fromView: collectionView)
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: (cell?.bounds)!)
if circlePath.containsPoint(newLocation!)
{
    //handle cell tap
}
```

Or in your subclass of UICollectionViewCell you can add something like:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: (self.bounds))
        if circlePath.containsPoint(point)
        {
            return self
        }
        return nil
    }
```

This will check if the tap is in the visible part of the view or pass the event to lower views. Then implement didSelectItemAtIndexPath and handle the tap event there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wanted to do this, but I laid out my cells so that other cells will be placed around the corner area of the square. I ran into problems trying to select the lower cells (`indexPathforItemAtPoint` kept returning the cells above the cells I want). I'll add these details to the question.

Comment: You might also try the suggestion I just added.

Comment: Is it also capable of handling pan gestures? i.e. if I want to pan over a bunch of cells, and register a pan over each of them.